# The meaning of 'stretch element'

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

what's the meaning of 'stretch' here?

"one of the questions that assists in preparing daily action list:

Is there anything else that may yield tangible results that I can do something towards today?(The 'stretch' element)"

Comment: There should be an explanation somewhere prior from wherever you got that text. In this case it's used as a stand-in for a larger explanation unique to this text, and therefore impossible for us to answer what the meaning is in this case.

Answer (score 1):

From experience, this is an extract from a piece about "Performance Management" otherwise known as a "Business performance review"

In that context, the reviewee is often rated something along the lines of "poor / okay / better than average" but the term used for the latter is often `stretch`, as in a person being 'stretched' professionally, as opposed to 'taking it easy'.